# How to extract specific string in a file using awk, sed or other methods in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with the following text (multiple lines with different values):

```
TokenRange(start_token:8050285221437500528,end_token:8051783269940793406,...
```

I want to extract the value of `start_token`  and `end_token`. I tried awk and `cut`, but I am not able to figure out the best way to extract the targeted values.

Something like:

```
cat filename| get the values of start_token and end_token
```

Comment: If you've already tried something, [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you looking to extract the two values into separate shell variables, or just print them out, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[(:,]' '{print $3, $5}' file
8050285221437500528 8051783269940793406
```

First value is `start_token` and last value is `end_token`.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -oP '(?<=token:)\d+' filename
```

Explanation:

- `-o`: print only part that matches, not complete line
- `-P`: use Perl regex engine (for look-around)
- `(?<=token:)`: positive look-behind – zero-width pattern
- `\d+`: one or more digits

Result:

```
8050285221437500528
8051783269940793406
```

A (potentially more efficient) variant of this, as pointed out by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) in his comment, uses `\K`, the variable-width look-behind:

```
grep -oP 'token:\K\d+'
```

`\K` keeps everything that has been matched to the left of it, but does not include it in the match (see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)).

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh, neat! The ultimate combo of shorter *and* more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

a sed version

```
sed -e '/^TokenRange(/!d' -e  's/.*:\([0-9]*\),.*:\([0-9]*\),.*/\1 \2/' YourFile
```